# WSO2 Automated test

Tags: automated-tests, wso2

I need to do some performance tests on a WSO2  platform deployed on premise servers, that platform includes a WSO2 5.7.0 cluster, a WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 cluster and a WSO2 EI 6.4.0 cluster. Making a search  I found very useful information about how to do automated tests:

https://medium.com/@kasunbg/introducing-wso2-testgrid-89089fe9efb0

https://github.com/wso2/testgrid

The WSO2 testgrid implements a great test scenario from scratch!, including infrastructure provisioning  and wso2 product installation. In my case, I just need to execute performance tests , but unfortunately  I can not find how to do it on the repository's documentation.

Does anyone have access to extra documentation abaut WSO2 Testgrid project?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 `TestGrid` was developed to test WSO2 products in different infrastructure combinations. `Testgrid` is intended to be used in-house hence there is very little documentation around it for external users to refer to. [Here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1EqHNstpZttBGZy7bw6QOUPbk8gmg2Px_jTMN3yJ6Msk/edit#slide=id.p1) is a Slide Deck you can refer to understand the problem Testgrid tries to address and the architecture behind it.

Coming back to your question. I don't think Testgrid is what you need. You can look at [performance-apim](https://github.com/wso2/performance-apim), [performance-is](https://github.com/wso2/performance-is) and [performance-ei](https://github.com/wso2/performance-ei) to perf test the deployments. These are also a bit complex to set up. So What I would suggest is to refer to the above repos and comeup with your own set of scripts(You can use Jmeter) to perf test the deployment with scenarios relevant to your business requirements.

Comment: Thanks you very much @yrc, the information about Testgrid has been very useful, I will take your advice and will prepare test scenarios based on existing repositories  performance-apim, performance-is and performance-ei